# Losing result data of Ajax call while storing in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, ajax

I have following code in which I am making Ajax call to get data. In success function I am creating an arrays (They are declared globally).

```
for (var i=0; i< arrayOf_ID.length;i++) {  
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: 'URL' +arrayOf_ID[i],
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: false,
        async: false,
        cache: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function (result) {
            for(var i=0; i<result.length; i++)
            {
                if(result[i].Comments!="")
                {
                    section[i]=result[i].section;
                    Comment[i]= result[i].Comments;
                    checklist[i]= result[i].checklist;
                }
            }      
        },
        error: function (error) {
            alert("");
        }
    });    
}
```

It is working fine, no error at all. but my problem is I am losing data while creating an arrays. I am getting result of ajax call perfectly but in array I am getting values of only last id.

Let's say: arrayOf_ID has 4 values (4 is just for an example, it can have 50+ values) and I am creating URL by each ID as shown above and I want arrays (of Section, Comment, checklist) of all 4 IDs together, but I am getting result in array(Section, Comment, checklist) of only last ID (arrayOf_ID).
Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 2):

```
for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
            if (result[i].Comments != "") {
                section[i] = result[i].section;
                Comment[i] = result[i].Comments;
                checklist[i] = result[i].checklist;
            }
        }
```

Instead of using section[i] = result[i].section in this ways value is overwritten instead you should use

```
for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
       if (result[i].Comments != "") {
          section.push(result[i].section)
          Comment.push(result[i].Comments)
          checklist.push(result[i].checklist)
     }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting the values in this loop:

```
        for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
            if (result[i].Comments != "") {
                section[i] = result[i].section;
                Comment[i] = result[i].Comments;
                checklist[i] = result[i].checklist;
            }
        }
```

The current values in all three variables ie section,Comment,checklist are overwritten by the next iteration and hence at the end of loop you get the last iteration values. The better way is to use an Object and store the values inside a key differentiated by unique identifier or keyword. The structure can be:

```
var Obj = {
        1: {
            section: [...],
            checklist: [...],
            Comments: [...]
        },2: {
            section: [...],
            checklist: [...],
            Comments: [...]
        },3: {
            section: [...],
            checklist: [...],
            Comments: [...]
        },4: {
            section: [...],
            checklist: [...],
            Comments: [...]
        }
        ....
    }
```

Comment: 4 is just for an example, the arrayOf_ID.length can be more than 30+ or sometime 50+.

Comment: @PruthvirajMohite you can then use push method of array to add data to arrays instead of overwriting